# How to override old design with new design(using master pages)?

Tags: asp.net

I am migrating the site from ASP.NET 1.1 to ASP.NET 3.5. I am using a new design layout with MasterPage concept. In previeous sites, some pages have UserControls. These are mixed with the old design. If I convert it using MasterPages, I am getting the old design combined with the new design. Please, can anyone help me? I am new to development.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you looking for an automatic conversion tool that converts user controls to master pages? I don't know of any, personally.

Answer (score 0):

The way you styled/designed controls in ASP.NET 1.1 was by adding attributes to the HTML of the control, for example a text input field with a white background and red border would have been marked up like this:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" BackColor="White" BorderColor="Red" runat="server" />
```

If your new design is using css, the reason the user controls are still using the old design is because these styling attributes have a higher precedence than the styles in your css.

The only way to get rid of the old design is to manually open each of your user controls and delete any styling attributes from the markup.